# How can I test Django Channels using native Django's test framework instead of pytest?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-channels

Django Channels recommends using pytest in order to get an async enabled testing layer.  I really don't want to throw another test framework into my project if I can help it.

Is there a way to use Django's TestCase natively to test Django Channels?

I've encountered multiple problems -- one is that async_to_sync() doesn't like to be called from the main thread.

I am limited with Python 3.6 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a reliable way to do this.  This is not made DRY yet, but is a proof of concept that appears to work for this test:

```
class TestWebSockets(TestCase):

    def test_message(self):
        async def wait_for_message(self):
            try:
                communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(application, f"/ws/channel/")
                connected, subprotocol = await communicator.connect()
                self.assertTrue(connected)
                data = await communicator.receive_json_from(timeout=1)
                return data
            except Exception as exc:
                logging.exception(exc)
                raise
            finally:
                await communicator.disconnect()

        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            future = executor.submit(async_to_sync(wait_for_message), self)
            DoTheThingThatGeneratesChannelMessage()
            message = future.result()
            print(message)
```